# Failed audit trying to report apparent bug in review queue

Tags: support, feature-request, review-audits

I opened up the SU 'First Posts' review queue just now and was presented with a nicely detailed answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/907474/can-hibernating-the-computer-damage-the-ram), about whether hibernation would damage RAM. The quirk was, the ID of the answerer was not shown:

[image: Page snip]

Thinking that was strange, I opened a new tab to look at the original post and found that the answer was by DragonLord, an extremely accomplished SU member. So, back on the review tab, I clicked 'Flag' and selected 'in need of moderator attention', with a message something like "this appears to be a bug in the review queue," trying to indicate that something appeared to have gone wrong, since the answer was *not* someone's first post.

I was terrifically ... put out, shall we say ... when the 'failed audit' message appeared, since I was most emphatically ***not*** trying to indicate any problems with the content of the answer.

Frankly, I don't think this is a case of "I failed the test" -- I think it's a case of "I saw through the test and thought the dang site was broken."  Implementation of some sort of 'dispute audit failure' feature, or another post-audit human interaction, would be greatly appreciated.  Also, I would appreciate this specious '[failed audit](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/377401)' being struck from my record, if that's possible.

Comment: As a note, if you suspect a problem with an audit, don't report it on the review page—this will be interpreted as an action on the post itself.

Comment: Well, yes, I know this ***now***. Would have been much more pleasant if I'd known it before the whole situation came up.

Comment: Why would you flag a question or answer that had no problems, you report a bug, by reporting it at the correct website not flagging it

Comment: @Ramhound, that sounds very belittling. Can you try to be a bit nicer?

Comment: @Ramhound It was unclear to me where else I should have reported such a bug.  There's no 'Report a Bug' link on any SE pages that I've seen, and it didn't occur to me to post a question on Meta.SU, if that's even the right way to report it.

Comment: @DragonLord This was my first audit - I didn't even know (or had completely forgotten) that audits existed! - so I thought it was a bug with SU itself, not a munged audit.

Comment: @Brian Meta Stackexchange is where people report Stackexchange bugs, Audit -> feature of stackexchange websites

Comment: @Ramhound So I've gathered. Thanks for making it explicit.  Is there somewhere in the introduction to the SE network (site tours?) that tells hopeless, fumbling, useless, n00ber users such as myself that meta.SE is the appropriate place for bug reports?  I may well have missed it in orienting myself to the network.  Most other services have a separate, relatively prominent 'bug report' feature/page, so if this isn't indicated someplace it might be a good idea to add notification somwhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about one or two failed audits. As previous questions and answers have stated, they worked on you - You took a moment to check that the post is actually OK. You're not a robo-reviewer just accepting every post that comes though.

Comment: Ok... how was I supposed to know not to worry about one or two failed audits? Audits aren't mentioned in the [site tour](http://superuser.com/tour), and searching the SU help pages for 'audit' currently yields [zero hits](http://superuser.com/help/search?q=audit).  Adding a link to a 'learn more about audits' page in the info box after an audit would be quite valuable, IMO. There's no context for how significant they are, and what the consequence structure is for, e.g., *x* number of failed audits.

Comment: That's definitely a good suggestion! I'd suggest raising it on Meta.SE, as it would affect *every* SE site in the network.